# Can't Open Multi-class program in cmd Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cmd, jar

So I want to create a calculator. I create Main and Addition classes (I know that code is messy and in Addition class i have every calculation, but this is test program), and everything work fine in Intellij, but when I want to open this in cmd I have a problem. Java can't find class 'Addition' in 'Main'.

```
C:\Users\skuza\IdeaProjects\Kalkulator\src\com\Cerelcode>javac Main.java Addition.java

C:\Users\skuza\IdeaProjects\Kalkulator\src\com\Cerelcode>java Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/Cerelcode/Main (wrong name: Main)

C:\Users\skuza\IdeaProjects\Kalkulator\src\com\Cerelcode>java Main.java
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                    value1 = Addition.getValueA();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
                    value2 = Addition.getValueB();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
                    System.out.println(Addition.addition(value1, value2));
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                    ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                    value1 = Addition.getValueA();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                    value2 = Addition.getValueB();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                    System.out.println(Addition.substraction(value1, value2));
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                    ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
                    value1 = Addition.getValueA();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
                    value2 = Addition.getValueB();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                    System.out.println(Addition.division(value1, value2));
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                    ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
                    value1 = Addition.getValueA();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
                    value2 = Addition.getValueB();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
                    System.out.println(Addition.multiplication(value1, value2));
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                    ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
Main.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                    ^
  symbol:   variable Addition
  location: class Main
17 errors
error: compilation failed
```

When I try to make .jar file I get this:

```
C:\Users\skuza\IdeaProjects\Kalkulator\src\com\Cerelcode>jar cf Main.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\skuza\IdeaProjects\Kalkulator\src\com\Cerelcode>-jar cf Main.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class
'-jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Btw I have JDK 15

Main:

```
package com.Cerelcode;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean shouldLoop=true;
        while(shouldLoop) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("1.Addition\n2.Subtraction\n3.Division\n4.Multiplication\n5.Exit");
            char symbol = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            int value1;
            int value2;
            switch (symbol) {
                case '1' -> {
                    System.out.println("Enter values: ");
                    value1 = Addition.getValueA();
                    value2 = Addition.getValueB();
                    System.out.println(Addition.addition(value1, value2));
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                }
                case '2' -> {
                    System.out.println("Enter values: ");
                    value1 = Addition.getValueA();
                    value2 = Addition.getValueB();
                    System.out.println(Addition.substraction(value1, value2));
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                }
                case '3' -> {
                    System.out.println("Enter values: ");
                    value1 = Addition.getValueA();
                    value2 = Addition.getValueB();
                    System.out.println(Addition.division(value1, value2));
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                }
                case '4' -> {
                    System.out.println("Enter values: ");
                    value1 = Addition.getValueA();
                    value2 = Addition.getValueB();
                    System.out.println(Addition.multiplication(value1, value2));
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                }
                case '5' -> shouldLoop = false;
                default -> {System.out.println("Error");
                    Addition.clearConsole();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Addition:

```
    package com.Cerelcode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Addition {
    public static int getValueA(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
    public static int getValueB(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
    public static int addition(int a,int b){
        return a+b;
    }
    public static int substraction(int a,int b){
        return a-b;
    }
    public static int division(int a,int b){
        return a/b;
    }
    public static int multiplication(int a,int b){
        return a*b;
    }
    public static void clearConsole() {
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
            try {
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("\033\143");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Broken classpath.  You understand what packages mean regarding where the class file are put?

Comment: No Unfortunately, i work in c++ and I remeber I could make my own libraries there, but idk if this is related to this

Comment: Classpath problems is (along with null pointer exceptions) some of the most confusing issues beginners have.  You need to understand how it works or you will be bitten again and again.

Comment: Dont think about "your own libraries". Rather step back and revisit such elemental basics. There are no detours. You better pick up a good book on Java and start working on that.

Comment: Ok then, thank you very much for letting me know what is the problem, i will read about this :>

Comment: Please post the error in the question itself, and not in an image.